# Mobile Backend Starter vs Appengine connected Android Project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

Can someone please explain the difference between `Mobile Backend Starter` vs `Appengine connected Android Project`? Is `Mobile Backend Starter` here to replace `Appengine connected Android Project`? The fact that two different technologies exist must have some meaning. So why is Google providing these seemingly (to me) competing approaches?

Answer (score 1):

They are 2 different things depending on where you want to start from and definitely there are overlaps in terms of functionality offered.

Mobile Backend Starter gives you both a Server and mobile client applications (Android / iOS). The Project is essentially a generic Mobile Backend As A Service (mBAAS) Project that runs on App Engine, gives you a generic data store, Push Notifications, Cloud Endpoints based integration in a ready to deploy package end - to - end. You can easily take this and modify it to provide an App Engine cloud backend for your mobile applications. To get these projects, you directly visit https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/ and get started.

An Appengine Connected Android project is for an Android project only with an App Engine backend. It sets you up with basic cloudendpoints integration and push messaging, but with no generic Cloud Datastore creation to store your data. You then need to hook/write things up. Here you will start within your Eclipse or Android studio environment.

Comment: `Appengine Connected Android project` is not for android only, although that is what the name says. You can get the endpoints for iOS or javascript through a terminal. It is just a lot more convenient to get the endpoint for android: push a button. The only convenience I can see from `Mobile Backend Starter` is that you can as well get an iOS endpoint from the a mouse click. So therefore once Google adds that to `Appengine Connected Android` then I don't see the advantage. Except perhaps in the term `Generic`, which I don't quite understand in the context and so will have to look up.